# change the style of products in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to change the style of products in `localhost/shop` and other categories, I found that I have to change the `archive-product.php`, but here we have `woocommerce_product_loop_start()` and `woocommerce_product_loop_end()`, and I am not sure where I should add my style.
for example I have a function for showing the price per unit and also stars for rating I want add them to the `<li>` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in the `archive-product.php` there is the following line and in fact the content in `content-product.php` loads on the archive page.

```
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
```

by going to `content-product.php`  you see `<li>` tag. by editing this file you can edit the style of products in WooCommerce.